# Run FreeBSD static binary on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, compatibility, freebsd

Would a very small/simple command line program, programmed in standards compliant C99, and statically compiled on FreeBSD work if executed on Linux ?

(I would test this myself but I do not currently have a separate HDD to test on Linux.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not in general, because the syscall interface is different. However, FreeBSD has a good Linux compatibility layer where you can run Linux binaries (that are compiled against the Linux syscall interface) on FreeBSD. There is such a layer available for both i386 and amd64 binaries.

See [Chapter 10: Linux Binary Compatibility](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/linuxemu.html) of the FreeBSD handbook for more information.

Comment: FreeBSD *host* can be either i386 or amd64, but only 32-bit linux apps can be run under emulation.